# VLC stuck in the wrong version on Linux mint 17 (Qiana)

Tags: linux-mint, apt, vlc, version

I'm currently using Linux Mint 17, and have been encountering a bug with VLC, the symptoms of which are a flood of zombie `sh` processes, progressively slowing down my PC (bloating the scheduler ?)

For this reason I decided to upgrade VLC, hoping that the newer version would be rid of the bug. That's when I learned that my version of VLC, 2.0.8, was all but the default version of Mint 17 (2.1.4). Which is strange, because I don't recall fiddling with the package manager.

What's worse is that when I went ahead and tried to upgrade, apt wouldn't see any new version. Same behaviour after trying out videolan's more unstable PPAs, and reinstalling the package.

What can I do ?

Here are the contents of my `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` :

```
tail -n +1 /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*
==> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/djcj-vlc-stable-saucy.list <==
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/djcj/vlc-stable/ubuntu saucy main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/djcj/vlc-stable/ubuntu saucy main

==> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/getdeb.list <==
# deb http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu/ saucy-getdeb apps 

==> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mc3man-trusty-media-saucy.list <==

==> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/n-muench-vlc-saucy.list <==

==> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list <==
# Do not edit this file manually, use Software Sources instead.

#id:linuxmint_main
deb http://packages.linuxmint.com/ petra main upstream import 
#id:linuxmint_extra
deb http://extra.linuxmint.com/ petra main 

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy main restricted universe multiverse 
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-updates main restricted universe multiverse 

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-security main restricted universe multiverse 
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ saucy partner 

==> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-toolchain-r-test-saucy.list <==

==> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-x-swat-x-updates-saucy.list <==

==> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/videolan-master-daily-saucy.list <==
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/videolan/master-daily/ubuntu/ saucy main 
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/videolan/master-daily/ubuntu/ saucy main 

==> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/videolan-stable-daily-saucy.list <==
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/videolan/stable-daily/ubuntu saucy main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/videolan/stable-daily/ubuntu saucy main

==> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/xorg-edgers-ppa-saucy.list <==
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/xorg-edgers/ppa/ubuntu/ saucy main 
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/xorg-edgers/ppa/ubuntu/ saucy main
```

Comment: It strikes me that you have quite a few `saucy` repositories in your sources, whereas Qiana is supposed to be based on Ubuntu 14.04 (`trusty`).

Comment: Moreover, I can't see a single trusty repository in there...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of all entries under `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` except for

```
getdeb.list
official-package-repositories.list
```

I have only those two on my Linux Mint 17 VM client system (and `virtualbox.list` in addition to that on my host). You e.g. move those files away instead of immediately deleting them:

```
sudo mkdir /root/tmp_sources
sudo mv /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*saucy* /root/tmp_sources
ls /etc/apt/sources.list.d/
```

after that do:

```
apt-get update
apt-get purge vlc 
apt-get install vlc
```

Comment: It seems that my system was in fact completely inside-out. The peak of which happened when I tried to `apt-get dist-upgrade`, and apt seemingly wiped `/bin` ("`unknown command sudo`" is no pleasant message). After a fresh reinstall, I now have the correct version of VLC, which doesn't exhibit the bug. That steamroller approach won't let us solve the mystery anymore, but at least it works now ! In any case, thanks again for your time and effort.